# How do I format an xquery expression in a xq, executed using Galax?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to execute XQuerys on an XML file.

I'm using galax to run those queries in an xq file.

How do I format those queries?

So within the xq file, the following format works:

```
fn:doc("filename.xml")/XPathExpression
```

How do I format an xquery expression to use with galax?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the syntax, then the [W3Schools XQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xquery_intro.asp) should be a good starter.